# Prove length of arc is the same as chord when $\theta$ tends to $0$

Tags: limits, circles

I'm trying to prove that the length of an arc is the same as the length of a chord in a circle when $\theta$ tends to $0$. Let

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
arc &=& \theta \\
chord &=& \sqrt{(1 - \cos \theta)^2 + \sin^2 \theta}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

If $arc = chord$ then their ratio should be $1$, so

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{(1 - \cos \theta)^2 + \sin^2 \theta}}{\theta} \\
&=& \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos \theta}}{\theta} \\
&=& 2 \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{\theta \sqrt{2 - 2 \cos \theta}} \\
&=& ?
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I happen to recognize $lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{\theta} = 0$ but I don't think I can use that while there's still $\cos \theta$ in the denominator. So that's where I'm stuck, how can I proceed or where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Do you know Taylor Series ?

Comment: Nope, I haven't learned that yet but I'm trying to prove this for myself. If there's no other way than Taylor Series, then I'll have to wait to fully understand the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that
$1-\cos(\theta)
=2\sin^2(\theta/2)
$

so that

$\begin{array}\\
 \frac{\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos \theta}}{\theta}
&= \sqrt{2}\frac{\sqrt{1 -  \cos \theta}}{\theta}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\frac{\sqrt{2\sin^2(\theta/2)}}{\theta}\\
&=2\frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\theta}\\
&=\frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\theta/2}\\
\end{array}
$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thanks, I also happen to recognize $lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1$ from the squeeze theorem or more simply by applying l'Hôpital's rule. It seemed perfectly reasonable to take the $\cos$ route but you took the $\sin$ route. Any advice on how I could've known?

Comment: As $\theta \to 0, \sin(\theta) \to 0, \cos(\theta) \to 1$.

Comment: Exactly, so considering I was trying to prove the ratio tends to $1$, it seemed perfectly reasonable to use $\cos$ because it also tends to $1$. Are you saying that taking the $\sin$ route is generally preferable, not just in this case, because $0$ will cancel things out?

Comment: In general, I like having things approach zero. It usually makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Usin Taylor series, $\sqrt{(1 - \cos \theta)^2 + \sin^2 \theta}=\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)}\sim_0\sqrt{2(\frac{\theta^2}2)}=\theta$

I'll edit this if I find another way. (Edit : see marty's answer)